# Building a simple SPARQL query for DBPedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am interested in querying the mapping of diseases to medical specialties using DBPedia and SPARQL. I'd like to write a query that returns a disease name, and the associated medical specialty name.

I know I can get a list of diseases with this query:

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?disease WHERE {
    ?disease a dbo:Disease .
}

ORDER BY ?disease
```

How can I also get the associated medical specialty? I am new to SPARQL and DBPedia!

Comment: Could you specify what the mdeical speciality is? If I look for it, I find it in `dbp:field`; is that what you are looking for? `PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?disease ?med_spec WHERE {
    ?disease a dbo:Disease .
    ?disease dbp:field ?med_spec.
}`

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested it [here](http://dbpedia.org/sparql); the following query should give what you want:

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?disease ?med_spec WHERE {
    ?disease a dbo:Disease .
    ?disease dbp:field ?med_spec .
}
```

That yields (just a few examples):

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Dengue_fever    http://dbpedia.org/resource/Infectious_disease_(medical_specialty)
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Dermatitis  http://dbpedia.org/resource/Dermatology
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Diabetes_insipidus  http://dbpedia.org/resource/Endocrinology
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Diabetic_ketoacidosis   http://dbpedia.org/resource/Endocrinology
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Diabetic_retinopathy    http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ophthalmology
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Diarrhea    http://dbpedia.org/resource/Gastroenterology
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Diarrhea    http://dbpedia.org/resource/Infectious_disease_(medical_specialty)
```